# cannot import s3fs in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, filesystems, python-s3fs

When i try importing the s3fs library in pyspark using the following code:

```
import s3fs
```

I get the following error:

> An error was encountered: cannot import name 'maybe_sync' from
> 'fsspec.asyn' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py)
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/**init**.py", line 1, in
>
> from .core import S3FileSystem, S3File   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 12, in
>
> from fsspec.asyn import AsyncFileSystem, sync, sync_wrapper, maybe_sync ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_sync' from
> 'fsspec.asyn' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py)

The `fsspec` package has been installed in my notebook. And I actually had been using it fine for a long time, when this suddenly happened.
I tried googling, but could not find this specific error.
Has anyone come across this before? And if so, do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Glad to hear this wasn't just me. It looks like if you pip install versions s3fs==0.5.1 and fsspec==0.8.3, that should fix it.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Also you have to change your bootstrap settings to install the older version of `fsspec` and `s3fs`. 
This issue was caused because s3fs released a new version on April 20th and it  doesnt use one of the functions that was in the old `fsspec`.  They need to allow for backward compatibility :(

Answer (score 0):

be carefull when changing the version of s3fs and fsspec ! in case your code turns even worse than before

```bash
pip install --upgrade botocore
pip install --upgrade s3fs
pip install --upgrade sfspec
```